# Testing redux async method with moxios

Tags: javascript, redux, axios

I'm new to redux and pulling out my hair trying to get a basic test to work with redux and moxios.

API is just axios, with some custom headers set.

I get an error on my post method: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

my method:

```
const login = ({username, password}) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(actions.loginRequested());
  return API.post(`curavi/v2/authentication`, {username, password})
    .then(response => dispatch(actions.loginSuccess(response.data.payload)))
    .catch((error) => errorHandler(dispatch, error.response));
};
```

My Test case:

```
describe('login', () => {

  beforeEach(function () {
    // import and pass your custom axios instance to this method
    moxios.install(API)
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    // import and pass your custom axios instance to this method
    moxios.uninstall(API)
  });

  test('calls loginSuccess when the response is successful', () => {
    const store = mockStore();

    const mockData = {
      data: { payload: 'yay' }
    };

    moxios.wait(() => {
      const request = API.requests.mostRecent();
      request.respondWith({
        status: 200,
        response: mockData
      });
    });

    const expectededActions = [
      {type: types.LOGIN_REQUESTED},
      {type: types.LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: 'yay'}
    ];

    actions.loginRequested.mockReturnValue({type: types.LOGIN_REQUESTED});
    actions.loginSuccess.mockReturnValue({type: types.LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: 'yay'});
    actions.loginFail.mockReturnValue({type: types.LOGIN_FAIL, message: 'boo'});

    return store.dispatch(operations.login({username: 'theuser', password: 'thepassword'}))
      .then(() => {
        expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectededActions);

        expect(API.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith('curavi/v2/authentication',
          {username: 'theuser', password: 'thepassword'});
      });
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you get a `TypeError` in `login` as you suggest? It doesn't make sense; you'd get that error if `API` were not an axios instance, in which case `API.post()` could return undefined. On the other hand, your test won't work for 2 reasons:

- You need to replace `API.requests.mostRecent()` with `moxios.requests.mostRecent()`.
- The function you have inside moxios' await won't execute for 0.5 secs, see [here](https://github.com/axios/moxios/blob/master/index.js#L385). If the return statement in your test were to be reached before then, your test would simply return a promise. You could do the following instead:

  ```
  test('...', async () => {

      // ...

      const result = await store.dispatch(
          operations.login({
              username: 'theuser',
              password: 'thepassword',
          })
      );

      expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectededActions);
      expect(API.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith(/* ... */);
  });
  ```

You should also make sure to set up the store correctly:

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);

// use your store inside your tests
const store = mockStore();
```

Comment: Thanks, turned out the root cause was kinda dumb.  I was trying to setup moxios from a module like in this tutorial: https://medium.com/@kilgarenone/use-jest-to-test-redux-async-action-creator-with-axios-in-a-create-react-app-app-d9c9b52eba5e then forgot all about it.  Once I removed that and changed the API.requests.mostRecent() like you said it all started working. Thanks!